# Smite Callouts?

Tags: pc, smite

I am new to Smite and I have only been playing for 2.1 hours and I'm really enjoying it. My question is, when I get into a more competitive Smite game, is there any callouts that I need to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In smite, people don't use chat to make callouts. They use the VGS system. When you press the 'V' key it will open a menu to the left of the screen, giving you choices of things you can say. It takes a while but you should learn as much of this system as you can.

Another thing you can do is hold the Alt key and left click the map. This will ping the map, alerting anyone on your team to go to that location. You can combine this with VGS to tell people to attack or defend certain areas.

The main callout you need to know is Gank: This is basically a surprise attack launched from the jungle. When someone calls that they will gank, you are expected to deal some damage to your laning opposition to make it easy for the jungler to gank. They will usually tell you which lane they will gank.

Just be sure you learn a little bit of the VGS system and the parts of the map.
 [image]
This map shows the buff locations (its the best I could find :P).
Purple Buff is Attack Speed
Red Buff is Damage
Yellow Buff is Movement Speed
Blue Buff is Mana
Gold Fury and Fire Giant are important objectives that will be explained by the tutorial if you walk near them for the first time.

From all this information callouts that people make should be pretty obvious. Good Luck! Enjoy Smite.

Comment: Should have mentioned that if you're in a team, you can use Curse Voice or Skype or any other third party voice chat system. This makes teamwork and communication easier.

Comment: Sadly, I'm level 30 and the only parts of the VEG system I'm really aware of is VVGG, VVVG, VEJ, and VEL. Of course, I mostly just play Assault. So, I really only need to tell people to group up for heals, good game, and to laugh and/or tell jokes at the beginning and end of the match.

Comment: It's not too hard to learn. For me, the whole chat system comes naturally. VG1 = Gank Left Lane. VH1 = Help Left Lane. VBE = Enemies Behind Us. VVVT = That's too bad.

Comment: I use a program called [Voice Attack](http://www.voiceattack.com) that uses voice recognition to activate keyboard commands. I've programmed in all of the VGS commands so that I don't have to memorize all of them, it works pretty well, I just have to say "Enemy Missing Right" into my mic and it issues the appropriate VGS command.